# How to prevent the application from Timeout expired Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, timeoutexception

Please help to identify the cause of exception from below Stack Strace:

```
Error=Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding., 

StackTrace = at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Core.ResService.DataAccess.SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction trans, CommandType cmdType, String cmdText, SqlParameter[] cmdParms)
   at Core.ResService.DataAccess.ReservationDal.SelectActiveResXml(Int32 resvID, String sessionID)
   at Core.ResService.BusinessLogic.Reservation.SelectActiveReservation(Int32 hotelID, Int32 resvID, String sessionID)
```

any Idea about the above exception stack strace like possible resolution and the causes will be appriciated.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=ADO.NET+TIMEOUT

Comment: By default SQL connections you create from within your application will time out after 30 seconds. If your query takes longer than that, you will get an exception. Either do some performance tuning on the query (add indexes check where clause etc.) Or increase the time out on your connection in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It tells you right there in the stack trace. Your SQL call timed out. Either fix the SQL call or increase the timeout. There is a timeout property on the command object, but you should really fix your SQL.